# How to make a blog page only display certain posts

Tags: wordpress

I have a Page in Wordpress that is a Blog Page Template. Now my issue is that it displays ALL the posts. I only want it to display posts assigned to a certain category

How do I do that?

Here is my blog.php page: I guess you have to edit it here right?

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Blog page
*/
?>
<?php get_header(); ?>

<div class="blog">

<?php 
$gogo_select_blog_sidebar_position = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'gogo_select_blog_sidebar_position', true);
$gogo_blog_link_text = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'gogo_blog_link_text', true);
$gogo_blog_link_url = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'gogo_blog_link_url', true);
$gogo_blog_text_no_posts = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'gogo_blog_text_no_posts', true);
?>

<header class="box-headline">
    <h4 class="main-headline"><?php the_title(); ?></h4>
</header>

<?php if($gogo_select_blog_sidebar_position=='right-sidebar-blog-template') { ?>
<!--Left content area-->
<div class="blog-holder">
<?php } else { ?>
<div class="blog-holder right">
<?php } ?>

<?php 
$temp = $wp_query;
$wp_query= null;
$wp_query = new WP_Query();
$wp_query->query('posts_per_page='.$gogo_blog_text_no_posts.'&paged='.$paged); 
$postcount = 0;
while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post(); $postcount++;
?>

<!--Begin post content-->
<?php
    // The following determines what the post format is and shows the correct file accordingly
    $format = get_post_format();
    get_template_part( '/lib/includes/post-formats/'.$format );

    if($format == '')
    get_template_part( '/lib/includes/post-formats/standard' );
?>
<?php if($postcount % 2 == 0) echo "<div class='clearfix'></div>"; ?> 
<!--End post content-->
<?php endwhile; ?> 
<!--Pagination -->
<?php if (function_exists("pagination")) {pagination();} ?>
<!--End pagination -->
<?php $wp_query = null; $wp_query = $temp;?>
</div>
<!--End left content area-->

<?php if($gogo_select_blog_sidebar_position=='right-sidebar-blog-template') { ?>
<!-- Right content -->
<aside class="sidebar right">
<?php } else { ?>
<aside class="sidebar left">
<?php } ?>
<?php get_sidebar('blog'); ?>
</aside>
<!-- End Right content -->
</div><!-- End .block -->
<?php get_footer();?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add your category to the WP_Query string:

```
$wp_query->query('posts_per_page='.$gogo_blog_text_no_posts.'&paged='.$paged . '&category_name=***yourcategory***');
```

Comment: Cool, thank you. Appreciate. One more question: I want to make another page with a Blog Page Template, but for this page I only want to display another category, but since it will be using the same blog.php page, how do I specify another category for a new page?

Comment: Have a look at the [template hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy), you might prefer to use `category.php` for this task. Of course, it all depends on your context.

Comment: thank you. really apreciate your answes. Got it to work. I copies the blog.php file and named it blog2.php. I changed the template name at the top and used the code to you gave me to only show posts from a certain category. So when I made a new page containing the posts, I just choose the correct template(thats where naming the template name ontop of the blog.php file comes in)